# how can i make the marginpar note have a number like footnote command does

Tags: footnotes, marginpar

how can i make the marginpar note have a number like footnote command does?
just like this picture show,
[image: this picture is going to show the marginpar note have the auto numbered label like footnote command does]

Comment: It does not answer the question, but I thought worth mentioning: check the `side` option of the [`footmisc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/footmisc) package (but it turns all footnotes into marginpars)

Comment: There's the [`sidenotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) package and the [`snotez`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/snotez) package. IIRC the [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class also provides sidenotes.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcounter{mparcnt}
\renewcommand\themparcnt{\textbf{\arabic{mparcnt}: }}
\newcommand\mpar[1]{\refstepcounter{mparcnt}\marginpar{\themparcnt#1}}

\begin{document}
\mpar{test}\blindtext
\mpar{test\label{p:test}}\blindtext
\mpar{test}\blindtext
\mpar{test}\blindtext

See margin~\ref{p:test} for a labeltest
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks，it's simple and beautiful, Does not use any package or class.that is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little improvement, to use the same style as `\footnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcounter{mparcnt}
\renewcommand\themparcnt{\textbf{{}^{\arabic{mparcnt}:}}}
\newcommand\mpar[1]{\refstepcounter{mparcnt}$\themparcnt$ \marginpar{$\themparcnt$ #1}}

\begin{document}
\mpar{test}\blindtext
\mpar{test\label{p:test}}\blindtext
\mpar{test}\blindtext
\mpar{test}\blindtext

See margin~\ref{p:test} for a labeltest
\end{document}
```